# Speed up Android emulator

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, qemu

I read on many other topics that the Android emulator starts really slow. Indeed, it takes +15 mins to start. However, on my machine is slow even after that.

The 'phone' responds with a 3-4 seconds delay and everything has a huge lag.

Is there any way to improve the performance of my laptop (Asus 1201N) is too rusty for the Android emulator?

PS: Tried in different emulator resolutions and the result is the same

Edit: My laptop has 2 cores with HyperThreading. And it shows as 4 CPU in Device Manager. However, when using the emulator, just one of the graphs is at 100%. Can I do something to make it work multi core?

Comment: As long as a single CPU device is emulated, there is not much the emulator can do to use more than one host CPU. So your measurements are ok. The emulator could however use the host GPU or further CPU cores to speed up it's OpenGL works, but currently there is no such implementation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you have "Disable Boot Animation" checked?

Also, if that doesn't fix it, one thing that helps is that you never actually have to close the emulator screen while you're coding.  If you click debug when it's already open, your APK will get uploaded to the emulator and start pretty much immediately.  For some reason it took me a while to figure out that I didn't have to manually close the emulator.

Comment: Where is the 'Disable Boot Animation' option?

Comment: Debug Configurations > Your Debug Configuration > "Target" tab

Comment: That's in Eclipse and it might make the emulator work better. However, the problem is that even when using the emulator alone, with no custom application deployed, it still lags hard.

Comment: That's just your laptop being old. I haven't tried this yet, but you can debug right on your phone. I am not sure if that will be faster though, but worth a shot if your lag is bad enough.

Comment: Yeah that's something to try.  You'll have to enable non-market apps and debugging on the phone itself, hook it up via USB and choose your device serial when you start debugging.

Comment: for the Eclipse Debug Configurations: does anyone know how to do this in Android Studio?  I want to remove the emulator launch screen.

Answer (score 9):

One thing I learned that helped me is that once the emulator is open from your first debug run you DO NOT have to close it. Leave it open, and on your next debug run it will be ready to go without any load up time like when you first open it.

In regards to your slowness after startup I suspect it's just your computer. It runs very fast for me. It starts up in about 20 seconds or less, and once it's open my subsequent debugs load very fast.

I hope at least my first tip helps to save some of your sanity.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you can try. It does speed up the emulator for me, especially during loading time.
I noticed the emulator is only using a single core of the available CPU. What I did is to set it to use all available processors.

I'm using Windows 7.

> When the android emulator is starting, open up the Task Manager, look under the Process tab, look for "emulator-arm.exe" or "emulator-arm.exe *32" ...right click on it, select Processor Affinity and assign as much processor as you like to the emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think there is few ways to improve the performance of your Android Emulator like

1. Use Snapshot, this will improve the boot time for consecutive application running
2. Use x86 Intel Hardware Accelerator
3. Use 3rd Party Emulator like BlueStacks

Hopefully it will help you to improve the performance and resolve your problems.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product. I am removing the link so no one mistakes this post for spam.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and in order to solve it I just disabled all the transition animation effects that are enabled under Spare Parts.

Answer (score 2):

it is way too slow for me too.
(slow on both my Pentium 4 (ubuntu) and my dual core 64 laptop (Windows 7)

apparently it uses QEMU - could I perhaps look for the image file and try a different version of qemu?

Another thing I tried is this: http://www.android-x86.org/  (in vmware) 
this seems MUCH faster but I can't get it to see the network!

(right now I just want to test some websites in the brower so seeing the network is a must - I'm not doing native apps just yet)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that instead of running the 'Debug' target, I just run the 'Run' target. The emulator runs a lot smoother when doing so. I only jump into debug mode if I really need it.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to network from android-x86, you neek to manual setup ip manual by use this command in console mode (Alt + F1):

ifconfig eth0  netmask 255.255.255.0 up

after do that, you can check it by type : netcfg in console and you can see this ip is set at your local wmware

you can check it success by ping ip you had been set in command prompt, and after that, you can use adb connect  to connect debugger to your virtual android

Comment: I tried same thing but I get an error No such device, and when I type netcfg, I see 5 devices, all down.